# Pycharm : conditionally run integration test

Tags: python, pycharm

In Pycharm, I would like to conditionally run integration tests, but always run unit tests.

```
Integration tests are named like this: itest_<module name>.py.  
Unit tests are named like this: test_<module name>.py
```

Can this be accomplished with some kind of run / debug configuration or some other configuration / code trick?

Comment: You can separate them into different directories and then `Run 'Unittests in <directory name>'` - [Performing Tests](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/performing-tests.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way that I handled this was that I named tests as test_ and integration tests as itest_.  Then I used discovery with the pattern *test_.